# npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0

Tags: angular, migration

I´m having trouble trying to remove this specific warning as i am preparing my application to migration.

> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

I checked out the deprecated message from lydell but i can´t still figure out how to remove this dependency as it only appears in the **package-lock.json**:

```
 "source-map-resolve": {
      "version": "0.5.3",
      "resolved": "https://nexus.org.br/repository/npm-all/source-map-resolve/-/source-map-resolve-0.5.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Htz+RnsXWk5+P2slx5Jh3Q66vhQj1Cllm0zvnaY98+NFx+Dv2CF/f5O/t8x+KaNdrdIAsruNzoh/KpialbqAnw==",
      "requires": {
        "atob": "^2.1.2",
        "decode-uri-component": "^0.2.0",
        "resolve-url": "^0.2.1",
        "source-map-url": "^0.4.0",
        "urix": "^0.1.0"
      }
    },
```

What is the best way to remove this warning?